# GWt 2.2.0 Freeze header row in CellTable

Tags: gwt

I need to freeze the first row(header row) of data in a CellTable, so that users can scroll through the data but still see the labels on the Header Row. The Header Row should not scroll when the user scrolls up and down, and the header row should scroll when the user scrolls left and right.

Is there any predefined method in the api of CellTable so that i can use directly.Can any one suggest a simple way to get this.

Thanks in advance

Surya

Answer (score 4):

What you want was added recently to the trunk, DataGrid: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.java?spec=svn10228&r=10228

I don't if it's going to be released in next GWT 2.4, but you can get it from the trunk if you really need it.

**Update:** Here is an example of it: http://showcase.jlabanca-testing.appspot.com/#!CwDataGrid

Comment: And more info about what is capable of: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10228
(I have no rep enough to add two links)

Comment: Why does this test app want to access my Google account? Any other examples?

Comment: Here's another example. This one shows source code. http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid